# Trying to understand how recursion works

Tags: java, recursion, methods, jgrasp

The code below asks the user to input a number and it adds each of the numbers up to get the sum. For example if i input 123 it will do (1+2+3) which will then output 6. I have the recursive method which is: 
public static int sumDigits(long n) however I am not sure when it is called or how it works, also what do long n declarations mean?

```
//this is my code
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a integer: ");

    long n = input.nextLong();
// Display the sum of all the digits in the integer
  System.out.println("The sum is: " + sumDigits(n));
}    

  //recrusve method that computes the sum of the digits in an integer
    public static int sumDigits(long n) {
       int sum = 0;

    while (n > 0)
      {
           sum += n % 10;
           n /= 10;
        }
     return sum;
   }
}
```

Comment: A recursive function is a function that calls itself. `sumDigits` is thus not a recursive function.

Comment: There is no recursion in your code. If you can't understand what long n means then it will be very hard to you understand recursion.

Comment: Obviously your question has nothing to do with `oracle`. Please review the tags the StackOverflow web site adds to your posts and edit them as appropriate. Doing it for you this time.

Comment: You shouldn't ask what `long n` means. If you can access StackOverflow, I am almost certain you can also access Google. Search for a meaningful phrase, I tried "Java long data type" - the first link it returned is this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html Then, get used to reading documentation - it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: There's not a clear question here. Maybe you're supposed to figure out how to rewrite the sumdigits function as a recursive one? It sounds like you need to become more familiar with the basics before you can tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for something like this:

```
private long sumDigits(long n)
{
  if(n <= 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  return n + sumDigits(n - 1);
}
```

Recursive functions perform one step in an operation, and then call themselves for the next step with some sort of end condition.

In this case, you want to add the current number to the sum of all the numbers below it until you reach zero.